# What does the operator //= do in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have this code to calculate the prime factors of n

```
def factors(n):
    factorlist = []
    k = 2
    while k<=n:
        while n%k==0:
            factorlist.append(k)
            n //= k
        k += 1
    return factorlist
```

What does the line `n //= k` do inside the while loop?

I've looked for the operator `//=`, but I don't find anything. I suppose it's what makes sure `k` is prime. But how?

Comment: [Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?#augmented-assignment-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator "//" is a ***Floor division*** operator, which is a division that results into a whole number which is **ALWAYS** adjusted to the left in the number line.

Example:

> 19//10 = 1
>
> 19/10 = 1.9.

Normally, this whole number adjustment, would result into the number 2, since it´s closer from 1.9 than 1, but a ***Floor division*** ignores that.

```
n //= k
```

is just like

```
n = n // k
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator divides `n` by `k` (integer division, with remainder) and assigns the result to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
n //= k
```

is the same as

```
n = n // k
```

where

```
//
```

will divide the two numbers on both sides of the operator, giving the correct answer without the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `help('//')` in Python to get more info. But here is the section that comes up:

```
Operator precedence
*******************

The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from
lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most
binding).  Operators in the same box have the same precedence.  Unless
the syntax is explicitly given, operators are binary.  Operators in
the same box group left to right (except for exponentiation, which
groups from right to left).

Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have
the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature as
described in the Comparisons section.

+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Operator                                        | Description                           |
|=================================================|=======================================|
| "lambda"                                        | Lambda expression                     |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "if" – "else"                                   | Conditional expression                |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "or"                                            | Boolean OR                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "and"                                           | Boolean AND                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "not" "x"                                       | Boolean NOT                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "in", "not in", "is", "is not", "<", "<=", ">", | Comparisons, including membership     |
| ">=", "!=", "=="                                | tests and identity tests              |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "|"                                             | Bitwise OR                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "^"                                             | Bitwise XOR                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "&"                                             | Bitwise AND                           |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "<<", ">>"                                      | Shifts                                |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "+", "-"                                        | Addition and subtraction              |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "*", "@", "/", "//", "%"                        | Multiplication, matrix                |
|                                                 | multiplication, division, floor       |
|                                                 | division, remainder [5]               |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| "+x", "-x", "~x"                                | Positive, negative, bitwise NOT       |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions